# PHP regenerating referral code

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function to generate referral code & then checking that referral code uniqueness by matching it with the database then completing the user registration. But my problem is, after generating code if system found duplicates then it needs to regenerate again. How to do that?
Here is the code below:

```
// Referral Code Generator
function genRandomString() {
$length = 5;
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$string = '';    

for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
}

return $string;
 }
```

Registration code snippet:

```
//---Ref code
    $ref_code = genRandomString();
    //checking if the referral code is unique or not.
    $stmt_rcode=$mysqli->query("SELECT ref_id FROM client WHERE ref_id = ?");
    $stmt_rcode->bind_param('s',$ref_code);
    $stmt_rcode->execute();
    $stmt_rcode->store_result();
    // if ref code is unique then only run the whole sign up process.
    if(!$stmt_rcode->num_rows == 1){
   // Complete the registration process here
  }
```

If $stmt_rcode->num_rows == 1 then I need to regenerate ref code again. How to do that?

**UPDATE**
For Generating referral code: I used following code which works faster flawlessly.

```
$test = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 5);
```

As I used ref_id as Unique Key. So obviously user will receive error in case of same value. Then user just need to reload the page again to regenerate. So far this is how I can make it work temporarily.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Warning says in the manual :This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value.

Comment: That's true but it would do a much better job than your function

Comment: uniqid already generates in 13 characters. So I don't have choice. Even if I use uniqid isn't will be good to check from the server side that if there is any duplicates or not?

Comment: With uniqid(genRandomString(),True) generates hf2e95965c2bae740a6.96531173 I need something in shorter form, like "78as9"